# Check video object in ExoPlayer2

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I have questions about `ConcatenatingMediaSource`. I want to play multiple videos and every time when one video ends,  to check one method. But in the case `ConcatenatingMediaSource`, he gives me to know about the latest after the end of the video, that is, at the end of the list of videos.

```
MediaSource  mediaSource;

for(int i = 0; i < videoList.size; i++){
    mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(Application.video_path + video.getName()), dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
}

ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatedSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(
            mediaSources.toArray(new MediaSource[mediaSources.size()]));

player.prepare(concatenatedSource);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Q: How do I get `STATE_ENDED` after every video or how to understand in `ConcatenatingMediaSource`, which ended with some video to check like this?

```
if (firstVideo = STATE_ENDED){
    textView.setText(video.getName);
//////
```

And is it possible to send in the arguments `ExtractorMediaSource` class instead of uri of the file?